# Date/Time C# using a substring

Tags: c#, while-loop, substring

This is the code I have so far, it will run an .exe so that when I enter my birthdate, it will tell me how many days that I have been alive.  Now, I need help with using a substring  so that I can edit the input where if a person inputs the wrong data, the program needs to ask them to input it again and again until it is correct.  I need to use a while loop.  Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalcDays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("This program written by Greg Ever");
            Console.WriteLine("Input your birthdate in MM/DD/YYYY format");
            string userValue;
            DateTime myBirthday = DateTime.Parse("04/15/2000");
            TimeSpan myAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(myBirthday);
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(myAge.TotalDays);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need is `DateTime.TryParseExact` I think. It gives boolean return if a `DateTime` format is not as you specify. While the boolean result of the `DateTime.TryParseExact` is false, you should just repeat the process again.

Comment: Says the type name TryParseExact does not exist in the type DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParseExact` to parse `Date` for a given format.

```
string userValue;       
DateTime myBirthday;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input your birthdate in MM/DD/YYYY format");
    userValue = Console.ReadLine();;

}while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(userValue, "MM/dd/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myBirthday));
```

Check the [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4DsEP)